# Clicking On-or-Through Image is Browser-Dependent

Tags: image, svg, cross-browser

I have found a difference between how Firefox and Chrome handle clicking near an image that I need to fix. I have a rect with an image occupying roughly the top 65%. I preserve the aspect ratio of the image and so it appears narrower than the full rect, which is perfect for what I need.

However, when I click near to the image, in the margin space either side of it, Firefox says I have clicked on the rect whereas Chrome says that I have clicked on the image. Inspecting the elements, I see that the image element spans the full width of the rect in both cases, but it is the functionality in Firefox that I need (as though I'm clicking "through" those image margins).

This is better explained with an example. The code below shows one rect and a narrow image in the top 65%. If I click either side of the image in Firefox, it says that the event.target.nodeName is "use" (I have the rect in a `<g>`) whereas Chrome says it is "image".

```js
function clickHandler(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    alert (ev.target.nodeName);
}
```

```css
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    pointer-events: none;
}

.m {
    stroke: dimgray;
    stroke-opacity: 1.0;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
    fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="TreeTest" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
    <g id="G-Box">
    <rect width="80" height="80" rx="5" ry="5"/>
    </g>
</defs>

<g id="HenryProctor">
<use tabindex="0" xlink:href="#G-Box" class="m" x="50" y="50" onclick="clickHandler(evt);">
</use>

<text x="90" y="106" dy="1em">Henry</text>
<text x="90" y="106" dy="2em">Proctor</text>

<image x="52.5" y="52.5" width="75" height="51.5" xlink:href="https://parallaxviewpoint.com/Images/Proctor_Henry_b1833.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" onclick="clickHandler(evt);">
</image>

</g>

</svg>
```

Is there a way to detect when the click was only on the visible part of the image?

[Edited for clarification] I need to distinguish between a click on the visible image and a click anywhere else in the rect. I have my event handler on both, but the action it takes depends on knowing what the user clicked on.

Comment: There is  [< >] button on the editor toolbar to convert your code in a running SO snippet

Comment: Interestingly, the spec says that width AND height are mandatory for the image (which is not helpful), but both Firefox and Chrome seem to ignore this. If I specify only height then it DOES seem to eliminate those filler margins, but the image is then left justified. If I could find a way to center it then it would work, but would go against the spec.

Comment: @ACProctor [the spec says no such thing](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement). See particularly Annotation 2 which says explicitly that height and width are optional.

Comment: I stand corrected, @RobertLongson. I had read the notes saying "this attribute is required" for both height and width at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image, and thought I'd seen it in the spec. My mistake.

Comment: I haven't accepted any of these answers as it seems to be a problem the specifications need to address. As I say in another comment, below, if the CSS pointer-events had an option for distinguishing the real visible element content from any extending padding then it would solve this issue. In my particular case, the SVG is generated by a design tool so I've been able to assess the aspect ratio of each image before generating code, but that's not really a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

That difference is an interesting quirk that I hadn't noticed before.

Although Firefox's behaviour seems the most useful in this case, I think that Chrome's behaviour follows the spec more accurately.  The blank areas on each side of the image are still technically part the "fill" of the `<image>` element.  So clicking there probably should return the "image".

Do you care whether the user clicks on the visible part of the image, or the blank areas beside it?  If not, then you could just tell the browser to ignore all click events on the `<image>` element using:

`pointer-events="none"`

Now when you click anywhere on the image, in Chrome, you get "use".

```js
function clickHandler(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    alert (ev.target.nodeName);
}
```

```css
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    pointer-events: none;
}

.m {
    stroke: dimgray;
    stroke-opacity: 1.0;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
    fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="TreeTest" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
    <g id="G-Box">
    <rect width="80" height="80" rx="5" ry="5"/>
    </g>
</defs>

<g id="HenryProctor">
<use tabindex="0" xlink:href="#G-Box" class="m" x="50" y="50" onclick="clickHandler(evt);">
</use>

<text x="90" y="106" dy="1em">Henry</text>
<text x="90" y="106" dy="2em">Proctor</text>

<image x="52.5" y="52.5" width="75" height="51.5" xlink:href="https://parallaxviewpoint.com/Images/Proctor_Henry_b1833.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" onclick="clickHandler(evt);"
       pointer-events="none">
</image>

</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: I need to distinguish between a click on the visible image, and a click anywhere else in the rect. In my example, both have the same event handler but it cannot, at the moment, tell what the user intended.

Comment: There's a fundamental disagreement between Chrome and Firefox as to how viewBox works. We (Firefox) say it applies to your contents/children but not to the element/container itself. Chrome says it applies to the element itself. The spec is unclear enough that both interpretations are potentially valid.

Comment: Thanks for your clarity, @RobertLongson. If the CSS pointer-events had an option for distinguishing the real visible content from the extending padding then it would solve this issue. It looks like I need to think of a radical alternative in order to fix this. I tend to use Firefox most of the time and so was unaware of this difference until it was reported to me.

Answer (score 0):

SVG content is in **shadowDOM**, so you can use `evt.composedPath()` to get the whole Event path.

`evt.composedPath()[0]` is the Element you clicked.

SO snippets have some delay issues with this; outputting errors in the console, and after a minute the wrong info in the attached SO snippet console.

#### Update

Argh! OP wants IE support (its 2021, even Microsoft says not to use IE)

For those who want a modern solution with native Web Components, where the IMG is read, and its `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are used to **generate SVG** from a Template

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/qv1n9khf/

```
<person-card img="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/..."></person-card>
<person-card img="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/..."></person-card>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this helps Danny. I do not know the size of the image in advance, and this case is just one of many image cases on the same page. There already is a rect behind the image (see G-Box group).

Comment: I meant the red rect to be an indicator on how to adjust ``<image>`` size. If you don't know the size, then load the image in an IMG, from the ``onload`` event get its ``naturalWidth`` and ``naturalHeight`` and use that to create the SVG dynamically.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, Danny. Ignoring that composedPath is not supported by IE, there could be hundreds of these images on a page, and so doing this calculation on all of them is going to be slow.

Comment: Alas, I updated the JSFiddle, but its a modern Web Component that does all the work, not supported in IE

Comment: IE is a PITA that I've put effort in to make work, Danny, but I'm on the verge of casting it adrift. The performance is the more important problem, but I'm also looking for a solution that doesn't involve HTML as I also have to support an SVG-only option. I apologise for that not being part of the question, but I assumed SVG could handle this.

Comment: No HTML... Server side you could use ImageMagick to resize images to the size required for your SVGs. For IE, do the maths... if you have to do X % to make things work for IE, You can't spend X % learning new technologies... you are getting **X % + X %** _**behind**_ every day.